# Loading KML file in Google Earth that is too heavy to be opened directly: Is possible to be made a local KML or HTML file that emulates a WMS link?

Tags: wms, wfs, kml, google-earth, overlay

I am trying to download a public layer because I have too many internet problems where I live now.

I was previously working with this layer named "SEC_DistroTM" on Google Earth through an "image overlay" that connects through WMS protocol to the URL:

`https://geoserver.exploradorenergia.cl/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&LAYERS=api_vector:SEC_DistroTM&STYLES=api_vector:api_sec_distro_tm_media_tension&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image/png`

But since its need to be continuously been actualized I am having problems because my low quality internet connection.

Using the answers to [Download online a public WMS layer as a Google Earth KML/KMZ that works without connection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416446), I was able to access to the GeoServer layer previews on the website

`http://geoserver.exploradorenergia.cl/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage?0&filter=false`

And from the "WFS" section of the "Select One" option button, I was able to download a KML file but restricted only to 50 elements (random for me, but always the same ones).

Following the advice of user @nmtoken I take from the Download Tab of Google Chrome the download direction URL and erase the section that says `maxFeatures=50&` so then I was able to download the full size KML file
`https://geoserver.exploradorenergia.cl/geoserver/api_vector/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=api_vector%3ASEC_DistroTM&outputFormat=application%2Fvnd.google-earth.kml%2Bxml`

But now, unfortunately, the file size of the KML was of 2.32GB so Google Earth is unable to open it, so I have now the info needed to be working offline, but I can see it.

Previously I have worked with some big SHP files, and when Google Earth cannot open them at once, a pop-up window dialog ask you if you want to open just the elements that falls in the current view letting you choose what you need to see, but the same thing doesn´t happened for the KML file, it just crashed.

Because of this, I tried to do the same trick with the SHP format file that is also available to download, but unfortunately erasing the `maxFeatures=50&` doesn´t work, I just get a Error Message website, and for others formats I tried, like GeoJSON or GeoRSS, but Chrome crashed trying to open it because it runs out of memory.

The only other available file I can download is an XML file named AtomPub, which weights 86MB.

I have already tried many Online converters of XML and KML files trying to get an workable SHP documents unsuccessfully, and also tried to download QGIS and GDAL unsuccessfully: one is too heavy to my old PC with Win7, and for the other one I tried to install it on an online Linux console on <www.onworks.net> to use ogr2ogr following the advice of @nmtoken in my other question, but I was unable to install it because my inexperience in Linux.

So now, since I can download from GeoServer a light KML file that links through WMS to the "SEC_DistroTM" layer, so it has already all the needed parameters properly settled, **I am trying to make/modify a light-KML file that links as an SuperOverlay/Region kind of file to the other heavy-KML file that have all the info offline, hoping I will be able to load the file piece-wise as I go surfing through the map**:

The original light-KML file has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns4="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0">
    <Document>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>68.92101395753197</longitude>
            <latitude>48.09695752959137</latitude>
            <altitude>7886700.163831234</altitude>
            <heading>0.0</heading>
            <tilt>0.0</tilt>
            <range>6372867.402972492</range>
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <NetworkLink>
            <name>SEC_DistroTM</name>
            <visibility>1</visibility>
            <open>1</open>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>-70.60364317911385</longitude>
                <latitude>-36.679087940974654</latitude>
                <altitude>5028233.302381102</altitude>
                <heading>0.0</heading>
                <tilt>0.0</tilt>
                <range>4063076.2475593667</range>
                <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <Url>
                <href>https://geoserver.exploradorenergia.cl/geoserver/api_vector/wms?service=wms&amp;request=GetMap&amp;version=1.1.1&amp;format=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml&amp;layers=api_vector:SEC_DistroTM&amp;styles=api_sec_distro_tm_media_tension&amp;height=768&amp;width=330&amp;transparent=false&amp;srs=EPSG:4326</href>
                <refreshInterval>0.0</refreshInterval>
                <viewRefreshMode>onStop</viewRefreshMode>
                <viewRefreshTime>1.0</viewRefreshTime>
                <viewBoundScale>1.0</viewBoundScale>
            </Url>
        </NetworkLink>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

I have already tried to modified it by changing the options of Google Earth enabling local files access, and changing the sections between `<href>` and `</href>` to the file path to the heavy-KML file:

`<href>file://C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/SEC_DistroTM-heavy.kml</href>`

But it **did not work**.

1. **Do you have any ideas of How to implement this layer Overlay in Google Earth to be loading the data of the other heavy-KML file already downloaded on my PC?**
2. **Do you have maybe other simpler way to make me load the required layer on Google Earth being offline?**
3. **Is possible to have this heavy-KML file with Line Segments to be loaded locally as it were a WMS link?, this through other light-KML? (a local KML or HTML file that emulates a WMS link)**

I have run out of ideas and I have zero experience with GIS data.

---

*Added later*

An example of how was structured the heavy-KML file from where I am trying to use as a overlay-layer, where Lines which I need to load by View/Region are named as "SEC_DistroTM.1", "SEC_DistroTM.2",..., so I think are ordered:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns4="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0">
    <Document>
        <Schema name="SEC_DistroTM_1" id="SEC_DistroTM_1">
            <SimpleField type="int" name="EMPRESA_ID"/>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="NOMBRE_EMP"/>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="PERIODO_ST"/>
            <SimpleField type="double" name="TRAMO_MT_I"/>
            <SimpleField type="int" name="TIPO_DISPO"/>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="DESC_TIPO_"/>
            <SimpleField type="int" name="COMUNA_ID"/>
            <SimpleField type="int" name="TIPO_PROPI"/>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="DESC_TIPO1"/>
            <SimpleField type="int" name="EN_ZONA_CO"/>
            <SimpleField type="int" name="CONECTADA_"/>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="IDENTIFICA"/>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="CODIGO_VNR"/>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="DESC_AISLA"/>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="DESC_MATER"/>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="DESC_TENSI"/>
            <SimpleField type="double" name="LARGO_RED"/>
            <SimpleField type="double" name="NUMERO_FAS"/>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="NOMBRE_FAS"/>
            <SimpleField type="double" name="PEEM_ID"/>
            <SimpleField type="double" name="GIS_ID"/>
            <SimpleField type="int" name="DATUM_ID"/>
            <SimpleField type="double" name="X"/>
            <SimpleField type="double" name="Y"/>
            <SimpleField type="int" name="ZONA_UTM"/>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="FECHA_INST"/>
            <SimpleField type="int" name="HusoCorreg"/>
            <SimpleField type="double" name="Shape_Leng"/>
        </Schema>
        <Folder>
            <name>SEC_DistroTM</name>
            <Placemark id="SEC_DistroTM.1">
                <ExtendedData>
                    <SchemaData schemaUrl="#SEC_DistroTM_1">
                        <SimpleData name="EMPRESA_ID">21</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="NOMBRE_EMP">COOPELAN</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="PERIODO_ST">012011</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="TRAMO_MT_I">3.0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="TIPO_DISPO">1</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DESC_TIPO_">A�reo</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="COMUNA_ID">8301</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="TIPO_PROPI">1</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DESC_TIPO1">Instalaci�n de distribuci�n de propiedad de la concesionaria</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="EN_ZONA_CO">1</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="CONECTADA_">1</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="IDENTIFICA">30148017</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="CODIGO_VNR">CDA3ACU3A006000</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DESC_AISLA">Desnudo</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DESC_MATER">Cobre</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DESC_TENSI">&gt;1 kV y &lt;15 kV</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="LARGO_RED">10.0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="NUMERO_FAS">3.0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="NOMBRE_FAS">RST</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="PEEM_ID">327358.0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="GIS_ID">0.0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DATUM_ID">2</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="X">720381.45</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="Y">5851491.67</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="ZONA_UTM">19</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="FECHA_INST">01-10-2008</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="HusoCorreg">1</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="Shape_Leng">9.75725641752</SimpleData>
                    </SchemaData>
                </ExtendedData>
                <LineString>
                    <coordinates>-72.50900864564723,-37.45740214291143 -72.50911883627103,-37.45740293552737</coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark id="SEC_DistroTM.2">
                <ExtendedData>
                    <SchemaData schemaUrl="#SEC_DistroTM_1">
                        <SimpleData name="EMPRESA_ID">21</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="NOMBRE_EMP">COOPELAN</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="PERIODO_ST">012011</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="TRAMO_MT_I">4.0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="TIPO_DISPO">1</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DESC_TIPO_">A�reo</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="COMUNA_ID">8301</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="TIPO_PROPI">1</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DESC_TIPO1">Instalaci�n de distribuci�n de propiedad de la concesionaria</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="EN_ZONA_CO">1</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="CONECTADA_">1</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="IDENTIFICA">20148018</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="CODIGO_VNR">CDA3ACU3A006000</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DESC_AISLA">Desnudo</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DESC_MATER">Cobre</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DESC_TENSI">&gt;1 kV y &lt;15 kV</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="LARGO_RED">4.0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="NUMERO_FAS">3.0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="NOMBRE_FAS">RST</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="PEEM_ID">327358.0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="GIS_ID">0.0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="DATUM_ID">2</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="X">741689.7</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="Y">5858385.1</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="ZONA_UTM">19</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="FECHA_INST">01-10-2008</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="HusoCorreg">1</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="Shape_Leng">4.01338972096</SimpleData>
                    </SchemaData>
                </ExtendedData>
                <LineString>
                    <coordinates>-72.27074479370563,-37.39001861714876 -72.27069958666758,-37.39001640184911</coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: One problem you have is the service itself seems quite slow.    You may try using the WFS to get a few features at a time, and create several KML files, either by using the startindex and count parameters, or boundngbox

Comment: @nmtoken thanks for the answer, I was studying yesterday about the protocol of KML language, and it seems to work by <Regions> but not for elements... I don´t know how the WMS protocol recognize the elements according the current view of google earth, I was thinking that maybe is possible to create a C++ file to create another text file KML that built the same structure.... but I don´t find yet much info about the WMS service and how it works....

Comment: @nmtoken  PS: finally I was able to use ogr2ogr to make the shapefile and it works, but is not too reliable since Google Erath only load at max 2200 elements randomly selected within the lines in the current view, so I don´t know how to "know" if every line segment was properly load

Comment: @nmtoken about the WMS emulation lecture of the KML file, it could be also from an XLM file which also can be downloaded fully, from an option named AtomPub (I don´t know what protocol is but is not too different from the KML file)... just in case where easier to think about working over this other file

Comment: AtomPub is an XML language, as is KML, so they look similar.

Comment: A WMS presents an image that it creates from the original data.   The server software generalises the data it presents depending on the scale of region requested, which is calculated through a combination of the size of the image requested (width and height) and the bounding box.

Comment: When you use KML (the light version) to reference a WMS, the URL is given like: `https://geoserver.exploradorenergia.cl/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&amp;VERSION=1.1.1&amp;REQUEST=GetMap&amp;SRS=EPSG:4326&amp;WIDTH=1024&amp;HEIGHT=1024&amp;LAYERS=api_vector:SEC_DistroTM&amp;TRANSPARENT=TRUE&amp;FORMAT=image/png` that leaves google earth to calculate the bounding box and send it per the request.

Comment: @nmtoken looks that the only way was to make an KML files that use the PNG split in <Regions> as a GroundOverlay, which is too complicated to do for me, and also if I download the PNG of that link is has much lower resolution compared with the lines displayed by the WMS link on Google Earth... at least, There is a way to Download the PNG/SVG file in high resolution without background modifying somehow that link?... maybe in that way I can use it as an Image Overlay after figuring out how to place it properly