# How to get a valid .kml file from database URLs?

Tags: kml, google-mymaps

I am quite new to GIS. I stumbled upon a problem for which it seems excessive to first study code and manuals for some weeks before I can solve it.

There is a map from an online database which I want to use. I tried mapping in QGIS, but without much success. I have taken peace with a simple Google My Maps for now. I hoped I could import that one map as a layer through a .kml file, but the database online provided URLs for WMS, WMTS, TMS, WFS, and I believe XML (https://www.pdok.nl/-/geomorfologische-kaart-nederland-beschikbaar-bij-pdok).

I do not know how to turn these URLs into a .kml *file* as there seems to be no simple converter online. There is https://edac.unm.edu/cgi-bin/wms2kml.kml which is supposed to convert WMS into KML/KMZ, but the KML file is only 1 byte and both formats get rejected anywhere I try them. To turn the WFS or XML URLs into a KML file is supposed to be easier, yet I cannot use code nor do I have tools like ogr2ogr as got recommended in this StackExchange ([Download online a public WMS layer as a Google Earth KML/KMZ that works without connection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416446/download-online-a-public-wms-layer-as-a-google-earth-kml-kmz-that-works-without)).

On this site I believe you can get an RDF file (https://data.overheid.nl/dataset/15431-bro---geomorfologische-kaart-van-nederland-1--50-000), but for the rdf2kml converter on this site (http://graphite.ecs.soton.ac.uk/geo2kml/) you again need a URL.

I am stuck in a very devious and rather pitiful effort, where all advice out there mentions API and getfeature requests, while this is not something I know a lot about and I was clearly not planning on doing something very advanced at the moment. Also, it seems that every converter or viewer says that there is no spatial data in my URLs or files.

Comment: There is a QGIS PDOKServices plugin  https://qgis.nl/2021/10/30/nieuwe-pdokservicesplugin-nu-met-metadata-link-en-hr-luchtfotos/?lang=en available that makes it easier to view and download

Comment: Do you actually need a KML or do you just want to display the data in QGIS?

Comment: When you write "There is a map from an online database which I want to use" - what do you want to achieve? There is a way to integrate WMS in a KML but if it is more about interacting with WMS / WFS / WMTS services, using QGIS is a very good tool. There are a lot of tutorials which will show you how to load WMS to QGIS For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3UTqQ6lw-M